# Reducing loading time of QGIS project

Tags: qgis, performance, qgs, amazon-web-services, loading

I have saved a couple of QGIS projects in a PostGIS DB, which is hosted in the cloud. The projects consist of different layers. When I open the QGIS projects, the loading time is very long. That is a problem because we have to switch a lot between the different QGIS projects.
The most important reason for the long loading time of the QGIS projects are raster layers which are hosted on AWS S3. They are only 5-10 MB but the QGIS debugging tool shows that their loading time is significantly higher than these of other layers in the QGIS project.

[image]

How can we reduce the loading time of QGIS projects with AWS layers?